# Facing issue with Javascript Remoting in salesforce

Tags: javascript, angularjs, salesforce, remoting

When I am making calls to my `@RemoteAction` methods in apex class i am facing issue like shown in figure. I am getting these errors sometime but sometime it works perfect.

[image: Response For remote call]
[image: error]

I am making call to apex methods from my Angular service as

```js
JSfunction: function  (data) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    ApexControllerClass.RemoteActionMethodName(JSON.stringify(data), function(result, event) {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
            if (event.status) {
                deferred.resolve(result);
            } else {
                deferred.reject(event);
            }
        })
    }, {
        buffer: true,
        escape: false,
        timeout: 150000
    });

    return deferred.promise;
},
```

Comment: is this in a Visualforce page?  Is the remote method in the same controller as the one defined in the page tag?  It looks like you're using this in Force.com Sites?  Can you provide more details please?

Comment: Hello Matt, Yes I am using with Force.com site, I have integrated Angular js with salesforce. I am using angular service to call apex method like above code.But issue is that I am getting unauthorized error and in response and I get error page which I have defined for 401 unauthorized.  Also main thing is that I get this error(401) for 2-3 service calls outof 15. If I goes refreshing it works fine

Comment: Check the field level security for the Site user's profile for the fields referenced in the 2-3 methods that are not working.

Comment: Hey Matt, If its security related then it should fail every time right? But in my case it works some time and some time not... its random behavior. if    **i refresh page 3-4 times every thing works perfect**